# Correct URI for REST calls to create & delete relationship between two entities

Tags: rest, web-services

I need to create and delete relationships between two different entities through REST calls.

Let's say user A (the current user) is going to follow or un-follow user B. The existence of a follow relationship is denoted by the presense or absence of the Follow relationship entity (Follow(B, A) means that A follows B).

Should the calls be:

```
POST /api/follow/{user-b-id} // to follow
and
DELETE /api/follow/{user-b-id} // to un-follow
```

where the identity of user A is deduced from the token sent along to authenticate the call.

Or should they be based on the action being carried out:

```
POST /api/follow/{user-b-id} // to follow
and
POST /api/unfollow/{user-b-id} // to un-follow
```

I have doubts about which methods (POST, PUT, DELETE etc.) to use and whether the URIs should reference the action (verb?) being carried out. Since I am re-designing an API, I want to get as close to "correct" (yes, I do realize that's a little subjective) REST API design as makes sense for my project.

Comment: Does the "unfollow" action have any other side effects?

Comment: As of now, the only side effects are the decrement of a couple of sharded counters (follower count of B, following count of A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Correct URI for REST calls to create & delete relationship between two entities

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your URI; `/182b2559-5772-40fd-af84-297e3a4b4bcb` is a perfectly find URI as far as REST is concerned.  The constraints on spelling don't come from REST, but instead whatever the local coding standard is.

A common standard is to consider a *collection* resource that includes *items*; such that adding an item resource to a collection is modeled by sending a message to the collection resource, and removing the item resource is modeled by sending a message to the item resource.  The Atom Publishing Protocol, for instance, works this way - a [POST to a collection resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023#section-5.3) adds a new entry, a [DELETE to the item resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023#section-5.4.3) removes the entry.

Following this approach, the usual guideline would be that the collection resource is named for the collection, with the item resources subordinate to it.

```
// Follow
POST /api/relationships

// Unfollow
DELETE /api/relationships/{id}
```

`id` here might be `user-b-id` or it might be something else; one of the core ideas in REST is that the server is the authority for its URI space; the server may embed information into the URI, at it's own discretion and for its own exclusive use.  Consumers are expected to treat the identifiers as opaque units.

> I have doubts about which methods (POST, PUT, DELETE etc.) to use and whether the URIs should reference the action (verb?) being carried out.

It's sometimes helpful to keep in mind that the world wide web has been explosively successful even though the primary media type in use (HTML) supports only GET and POST natively.

Technically, you can use POST for everything.  The [HTTP uniform interface](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) gives you carte blanche.

`PUT`, `DELETE`, `PATCH` can all be considered specializations of `POST`: [unsafe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) methods with additional semantics.  [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) suggests idempotent replace semantics, [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) suggests remove, [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) for an all or nothing update.

Referencing the action isn't *wrong* (REST doesn't care about spelling, remember), but it does suggest that you are thinking about the *effects* of the messages rather than about the *resources* that the messages are acting upon.

[JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) may be a useful example to keep in mind.  The [operations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4) (add, remove, replace, and so on) are encoded into the patch document, the URI specifies which *resource* should be modified with those operations.

[Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc) expressed the idea this way - HTTP is a document transfer application.  Useful work is a side effect of exchanging documents.  The URI identify the documents that are used to navigate your integration protocol.

So if you need consistent, human readable spellings for your URI, one way to achieve this is by articulating that protocol and the documents from which it is composed.

> Would it be correct to say that PUT is for replacing the entire entity (resource) and PATCH if for modifying a sub-set of the entity's (resource's) properties?

Not quite.  PUT means the message-body of the request is a replacement representation of the resource.  PATCH means the message-body of the request is a patch document.

There's nothing in the semantics that prevents you from using PUT to change a single element in a large document, or PATCH to completely replace a representation.

But a client might prefer PATCH to PUT because the patch document is much smaller than the replacement representation.  Or it might prefer PUT to PATCH because the message transport is unreliable, and the idempotent semantics of PUT make retry easier.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that `PUT` is for replacing the entire entity (resource) and `PATCH` if for modifying a sub-set of the entity's (resource's) properties?

Answer (score 1):

The right decision also depends on the way other resources are mapped in the project. Same style is better, however if there's no preference, the following could have the advantage of being easier to implement and remember

```
POST /api/follow/{user-b-id} // to follow
and
POST /api/unfollow/{user-b-id} // to un-follow
```

Comment: Re-designing from scratch, so there are no other resource mappings to consider for the sake of consistency.

Comment: In this case maybe the other option would suit better since it is closer to the 'right' RESTful design

Answer (score 1):

I would say, use the delete verb if your are passing in the id of the relationship/link/follow from a to b.  This way, it is fairly explicit your route is doing.  It is accepting an id of some object and deleting it.

However, in your example, you are passing in the id of the other user, then you have to do some logic to find the relationship/link/follow object between the two and delete it.  In my mind, this is more of a post than a delete because of the additional work you have to do.  Regardless, it seems fairly subjective as to which one is "right",